# Azure Notification Hub & Android with Firebase

Tags: android, azure, notifications, token, azure-notificationhub

I'm having a problem with NOTIFICATION HUB and Firebase.
The same Notification Hub is WORKING with iOS and Firebase is working with the "test notification" from the site.

Actually I have a configuration with GMC where I put in the key I found on Firebase in:

```
Firebase -> Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Server Key
```

The device are correctly registered in Notification Hub but when I try to send a notification I get:

```
The Token obtained from the Token Provider is wrong
```

I Already tried to delete and recreate a new Notification Hub but I face the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue where I created a new Firebase project and came into the same issue. What I had to do was import an existing project from Google (there's an import option in the Firebase console) created through the Google developer console. Then I used the messaging token from that project that's been imported into Firebase and was able to send a test notification without running into the wrong token error